# Is there a way to allow external users to send emails to my list

Tags: 2013, email, administration, configuration, smtp

I am working on SharePoint server 2013, and i have added an Announcement list. then i configure the announcement list to receive in-coming emails,so currently our domain users can send an email to the following address `ListA@OurSharePointServerName.com` and a new item will get created inside the list.

But of course if external users try to send an email to `ListA@OurSharePointServerName.com` it will not reach the list , at-least since `OurSharePointServerName.com` is not available to public users .. So is there a way to force this to work , so external users can send emails which will get populated inside our SharePoint list ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the server name as the domain name of your incoming email, use an Internet one.
Let's say your company domain name is `company.com`:

1. Register `sharepoint.company.com` (or anything else) as an MX entry in DNS.
2. Make it point to your company mail server
3. On the mail server (let's assume Exchange), create a connector to route all emails sent to `...@sharepoint.company.com` to the SP server in your farm that hosts the SMTP service.
4. On the IIS 6.0 console of your SP server, add a domain as an alias: sharepoint.company.com.
5. In the incoming email settings (Central Admin of SP), set the domain as `sharepoint.company.com` as well.

Comment: ok  i got your point , i will try this .. atleasy based on your reply,  i can say that this is something that is achievable inside SharePoint ...  so this is great ..

Comment: i came across this question again. but can you please adivce why i need to register "sharepoint.company.com" as an MX entry in DNS server ? i mean can i use our company domain as-is such as company.com and have the email inside the list as follow listA@comapny.com ?  of course i need to create a connector on exchnage which will route any email send to listA@company.com to the sharepoint server which have the SMTP server ?is this possible, or i need to register a new MX entry in DNS ?

Comment: It is possible to use `company.com` domain. As you stated, this means the Exchange connector will be configured to detect complete address `listA@company.com`. and not the easiest rule "all emails sent to `@SharePoint.company.com`". What happens when you configure a new `listB@company.com`? You'll need to re-config your connector...

Comment: you are correct, but we want external users to be sending us emails and have these emails saved inside the lists. and we want them to use an easy email address (standard) email address, such as "ContactUs@company.com" or "info@company.com". without having to specify sharepoint. so in this case we will create a connector inside exchnage to route any email send to info@company.com to the SharePoint server where we have enabled the SMTP? in this correct?. now if we want to configure another list, in this case we need to create a new connector to router for example contactus@company.com

Comment: Yes, you're correct.